# Por que se chamam "bissextos" os anos que têm mais um dia?

Tags: origem, nomes, morfema

A meu ver, a palavra *bissexto* é formada por dois morfemas: *bi*, dois, e *sexto*, seis; portanto a combinação destes morfemas pareceria significar "a cada dois seis (12) anos" ou "duas vezes em cada seis (3) anos".

Contudo, ignorando as restantes regras sobre se um ano o é ou não, os anos bissextos, que têm mais um dia para ajustar ao período de translação da Terra, ocorrem a cada *4* anos. Qual é portanto o motivo para este termo, a meu ver, impróprio? Qual é a sua origem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

De acordo do dicionário do latin "Lewis & Short", a palavra latim [*bi-sextus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=bisextus#lexicon) significou *dia intercalar*. Isto é porque, em vez de acrescentar um dia 29 ao mês de Fevereiro, os romanos duplicaram o dia 24. Os romanos contaram os dias do mês [duma forma diferente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Februarius#Dates) do que hoje. O dia 24 de Fevereiro se escrevia

> a.d. **VI** Kal. Mart.

que era abreviatura para

> ante diem **sextum** Kalendas Martias

que significou

> o **sexto** dia antes do primeiro do Março

Então neste sentido o dia intercalar era um dia "bi-**sextum**". O dia antes era o festival [Terminália](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termin%C3%A1lia_(festival)), que era considerado o dia final do ano religioso.

Comment: Ingenuamente, eu achava que era 'bissexto' porque de 365 dias passava para 366, logo, com dois números seis....

Comment: Um ano Bissexto tem 366 dias! Bissexto porque tem dois 6 no fim!

Comment: "Um ano com dois dias que são 6 dias antes de primeiro de Março", uma forma peculiar de se contar. Praticamente um dia com 48 horas!

Answer (score 0):

[Adar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adar) (em hebraico: אֲדָר‎) é o 6º (sexto) mês civil e o 12º (décimo segundo) mês religioso do calendário judaico.
Quando temos dois meses de ADAR num determinado ano judaico, isso denomina o Ano como bissexto (Sao dois meses de ADAR = bi sexto mes)

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Note que, ao copiar texto de uma fonte, como a Wikipedia, é importante citá-la (dessa vez incluí o link para você — edições que melhorem postagens alheias, sem alterar a intenção do autor, são bem-vindas). Com relação ao conteúdo da resposta, apesar de interessante, seria fundamental incluir alguma evidência de que o calendário judaico teve alguma influência sobre a adoção da palavra "bissexto", em português, dado que é disso que trata a pergunta: qual é a origem do termo "bissexto". Caso contrário sua postagem não constitui uma resposta.